# Possible reasons for SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We have 2 domains.

- Domain A is resource domain
- Domain B is user domain
- Domain A contains a web site With Windows authentication
- The Group All Domain Users in domain B is given Access to the web site
- When we try to Access the web site we get a password Challenge
- inputing user name and password results i Access denied
- The error code in the IIS log was 2146893048
- Googling 2146893048 gave SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN

What are the possible reasons for SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN?

Answer (score 0):

SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN Is a kerberos error: The function failed. The token passed to the function is not valid.

This could be anything from clock skew to no domain trusts.